# .htacces rewrite, remove inner part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are lots of questions about this topic and i tried a lot of answers, now i found onw working, but the flexibility is missing

i got a folder strucure like

profile/user/username

now i want the the url to be shortened to

/username

the working version i got is this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profile/user/specialuser [NC]
RewriteRule ^specialuser/(.*)$ /profile/user/specialuser/$1 [L]
```

so using exactly this url, /profile/user/specialuser is transformed to /specialuser, but how can i keep it flexible, that [specialuser] is a placeholder for all the upcoming usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty much there already. You use another capture group, and another placeholder in the rewritten string that is replaced by that capture group. The condition seems useless to me, so I removed it.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /profile/user/$1/$2 [L]
```

`[^/]` matches a character that is not the `/` character. It is to make sure it matches only the first part of the url.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. the problem with this version is, that all the other urls, like /profile/general/ or /profile/general/settings/ (no user in between) don't work anymore, and my stylesheets are not found anymore, which are placed in the profile-folder (not profile/user!). did i miss somethin?

Comment: add a condition that excludes those specific folders: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(css|js|profile|unicorns)`

Comment: but it means excluding every single folder except user, isn't there a way to just rewrite, when /user is part of the url

Comment: You want to rewrite `example.com/username` to `/profile/user/username/` on the server... You know nothing about `username`, other than that it does not contain a slash. You might be able to do an unnecessary does-this-directory-exist check for each url that is entered. It unnecessarily adds a lot more overhead to this. This is simply the trouble you created for yourself by deciding that you wanted different urls.

Comment: thanks for your patience, really! i wanna do the rewrite the other way around. i've got /profile/user/username/ and i want it to be /username/. so everytime, /profile/user/ is in the path, it should be shortened out... without any exception.

Comment: Yes, so the client sends the following url to your server `example.com/username`. The server can either respond with "404 Not Found - There is no such file 'username' on this server" or you can internally rewrite that to a file it *can* handle. You should not link to `profile/user/username` anywhere on your site.

Comment: ok, i think i've got it now, would be easier to insert another part, like show/ and then there could be a general redirect ... RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /profile/user/$1 [L], and it's /show/specialuser1 - /show/specialuser2 ...thanks!